# Welche "wohin"- und "woher"-Adverbien entsprechen "drinnen"?

Tags: grammar, adverb

Ich habe ein Problem, ich lerne die lokale Adverbien, aber ich verstehe nicht, warum ich in meinem Lehrbuch die folgende Seite über das Adverb *drinnen* habe

[image]

und [hier](http://www.mein-deutschbuch.de/lernen.php?menu_id=72#vergleich) und [hier](http://www.deutschegrammatik20.de/adjektiv/adverb/adverbien-lokal/) habe ich *rein* im *wohin?*-Fall.

Kann jemand mir das erklären?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Du sitzt einem kleinen Missverständnis auf.

> Otto war draußen gewesen.
>   Dann ging er rein.
>   Nun ist er drinnen.

Dein Buch hat jeweils eine Vergangenheitsform (Mit Adverbiale des Ortes) gebildet, und dann die Bewegung von dieser Vergangenheit weg in die Gegenwart beschrieben. Du siehst also das *rein* neben *draußen*, weil Otto draußen *gewesen sein muss*, bevor er reingehen kann.

Umgekehrt hast du neben *drinnen* nur *raus*, weil er, wenn er drinnen ist, nicht mehr irgendwo hineingehen könnte, sondern nur noch herauskommen kann.

---

Zusatznotiz: Ich habe hier absichtlich die Abstufung Plusquamperfekt – Perfekt – Präsens gewählt, um die zeitliche Abfolge überdeutlich zu machen. Diese Konstruktion ist so zwar nicht falsch, aber *es ist auch nicht üblich* in diesem Zusammenhang das Plusquamperfekt zu benutzen.

Comment: leider habe ich ein wenig Konfusion

Comment: @mle Das ist nicht deine Schuld, sondern die des Lehrbuchs, das Umgangs- und Schriftsprache in verwirrender Weise vermischt. Ich habe den starken Verdacht, dass hier noch weitere Fragen dazu von dir kommen werden, und empfehle dir, soweit möglich, zusätzlich ein anderes Hilfsmittel zu verwenden.

Comment: Alles in Ordnung, am Ende habe ich die Jans Antwort verstanden. Danke! :)

Comment: @Jan: Entweder Präteritum: »Otto war draußen« (ohne *gewesen*), oder Perfekt: »Otto *ist* draußen gewesen.«. Das was du geschrieben hast (»Otto war draußen gewesen«) ist der Plusquamperfekt (wörtlich etwa: »Mehr als Vergangenheit«). Diese Zeitform erfordert aber die Anwesenheit einer anderen Handlung, die in der Vergangenheit stattgefunden hat, und auf die sich das Draußen-Sein bezieht. Etwa so: »Otto war draußen gewesen *bevor es zu regnen anfing*.« Ohne das vergangene Ereignis, vor dem ein anderes Ereignis stattgefunden hat, ist die Verwendung des Plusquamperfekt nicht angebracht.

Comment: @mle: »Ich habe Konfusion« klingt so, als hättest du eine Krankheit, deren Name *Konfusion* ist. (»Ich habe Schnupfen«, »ich habe Halsweh«, usw.) So konstruiert man keinen Satz, in dem ausdrücken will, dass man verwirrt ist. Man sagt stattdessen: »Ich bin verwirrt«. Dein Kommentar müsste also so lauten: »Leider bin ich ein wenig verwirrt.«

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Ich habe das Plusquamperfekt absichtlich gewählt, weil Otto draußen *gewesen war*, bevor er *rein ging* um nun *drin zu sein*.

Comment: @Jan: Trotzdem ist es - vor allem beim Anschluss mit *dann* - gemessen am traditionellen Sprachstandard eine exzessive Verwendung des Plusquamperfekts. Darüber, ob man das schon als korrekt werten kann, kann man sich sicher streiten. Aber jedenfalls hat es sich noch nicht allgemein durchgesetzt.

Comment: @Jan: Auch eine absichtliche Verwendung kann eine falsche Verwendung sein. So wäre es richtig: »Otto war draußen. Dann ging er rein. Nun ist er drinnen.« oder: »Otto **ist** draußen gewesen. Dann ging er rein. Nun ist er drinnen.« Welche der beiden Varianten »richtiger« ist, hängt davon ab, ob du deutsches Deutsch oder österreichisches Deutsch verwendest. Präteritum wird in Deutschland bevorzugt, Perfekt in Österreich (die beiden Zeitformen werden in D und A nicht nur unterschiedlich verwendet, sondern haben auch unterschiedliche deutsche Bezeichnungen). Plusquamperfekt ist in D und A falsch.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Gerade von dir hätte ich noch erwartet, dass du den Unterschied zwischen Nord- und Süddeutschland beachtest; Präteritum ist höchstens in Norddeutschland bevorzugt. Ob es falsch ist … hm, ich bleibe bei »nein«. Wenn du einen Vorschlag hast, wie ich das schreiben kann, *und gleichzeitig die Abfolge der Ereignisse immer noch überdeutlich bleibt* (nur ein *dann* reicht nicht, sonst wäre die Frage nicht gestellt worden), gerne her damit.